# Interpreting SSH information on Windows Event Viewer.... sshd: Did not receive identification string from ipaddress on port portnumber

Tags: windows, incident-response, openssh

I am currently reading through Windows Event Log (OpenSSH) looking at the artefacts created by an attack, I am trying to understand the meaning of certain notifications.

A brute force attack was made by myself, from a Kali Linux machine and the software I use was Metasploit.

In Kali Linux when I ran the nmap command on the target machine, I looked instantly at Windows Event Viewer and received this SSH notification:

- “sshd: Did not receive identification string from *ipaddress* on port *portnumber*”

I was hoping to receive information about the attacker machine (Linux) such as name of machine or user or is this not possible?

Comment: what information are you looking for?

Comment: Information about the attacker or the Linux machine. All I’m receiving is the IP address. Just wondering if it’s an issue with the SSH server or that’s all the Event Log presents

Comment: What attack was made?What information are you hoping to gain other than ip address?Be a bit more specific in the question.

Comment: Brute force attack. Information such as the name of the attacker machine or the name of user that implemented the attack

Comment: Why would a scanning tool send information about the person using it? It would have to know how to speak the protocol in order to communicate over it, but I don't understand the premise behind this question.

Comment: I’m just trying to understand artefacts created by an attacker. Just wondering if any details about the attacking machine are left on the victim (target) machine that I can trace. Hence the question........................

Comment: @C.Mann yes, with a network scan, the only information possibly available will be the IP and TCP headers. So, IP addresses, ports, etc. I suppose you could passively fingerprint the scanner's OS by looking at the TCP values, but likely only if a full-connect scan was used.